# Volume function for changing html not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a working volume slider but I can't get it to update the volume and the number next to it showing the volume

I get this error in the console `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')`

Someone on another post said that `.value` needs to be added on top of the `sound` variable

```js
function volume_change(id) {
  var sound = document.getElementById("input-" + id);
  volume_show.innerHTML = sound.value;
  sound.volume = sound.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="volume">
  <p id="volume_show">
    50
  </p>
  <i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="mute_sound()" id="volume_icon"></i>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" onchange="volume_change(this.id)" id="3">
</div>
```

Comment: um, the id is not `"input-3"`, that is never going to match `id="3"`

Comment: The slider value is `this.value`, not `sound.value`. And you need to set `sound` to the `<audio>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` is 3 and not `input-3`. This should work.

```
function volume_change(id){
                        var sound = document.getElementById(id);
                        volume_show.innerHTML = sound.value;
                        sound.volume = sound.value;
                    }
```

If you're looking to select multiple tags with input type then go for `querySelector`